# Doesn't find application.properties via @PropertySource

Tags: spring, application.properties

I have a SpringBootApplication and within this context, I want to add a @Bean from another project depending on the application.properties of that project. But I can't make the @ConfigurationClass read the correct application.properties. It always reads the application.properties in the SpringBootApplication's project.

First, I let the SpringBootApplication scan my @Configuration class. The configuration class looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RuntimeSpringConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myProperty", havingValue = "myValue")
    public myClass getMyClass() { return new myClass()}
}
```

The structure of the project is the default structure created by maven:

```
src
-main
--java
---myClass
---RuntimeSpringConfig
--resources
---application.properties
```

It only creates the bean, if I also add the property-value pair to the application properties in the SpringBootApplication project.

Comment: The propblem does not seem to be Spring reading the file. If I change the argument of @ConditionalOnProperty it gives an IOException.

Comment: I have learnt the reason could be the order in which spring builds up the application context. @PropertySource has low priority.